# How to run SQL Server 2012 Services

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2012

I have Installed Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 (Ultimate) , and it installed all the SQL files,
yet I can't find the SQL Server Manager in the Start Menu, like the old version, so I can't start the services,  , or there is an other way to run the services, so I can connect to the SQL Server?

[image: here an Image of the Installation]

Answer (score 1):

In Run window, type `"C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mmc.exe" /32 C:\windows\SysWOW64\SQLServerManager12.msc`. I did come across the same problem (Sql Server Configuration Manager is not in start menu) before, and I had to pin it to task bar.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Sever 2012 service are installed via [Microsoft® SQL Server® 2012 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29062) as VS 2012 does not install it unless you are using custom installer..

Once you install Microsoft® SQL Server® 2012 Express in your machine you can use SSMS and other tools to manage SQL services on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

Use 'sqlserver.exe' to start SQL Server from the command line - MSDN reference [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162819).  Or you can download SQL Server Management studio as shown below - from this [link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29062).

[image]